# The specified schema name either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to create replica of my database from SQL server to another.
For that I am generating script from original server and trying to run in another server. I've created database manually with the same name.

Here is the screenshot of original database
[image]

When I generate script, following script is created which I am trying in another server

```
USE [ContactsApp]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [common].[BU]    Script Date: 2/12/2016 3:02:29 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [common].[BU](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IndustryID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BU] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Code] [varchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [CreateTime] [time](3) NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [ModifyDate] [date] NULL,
    [ModifyTime] [time](3) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_BU] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [UK_BU_Code] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Code] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [UK_BU_Name] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [BU] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [common].[BU] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_BU_CreateDate]  DEFAULT (CONVERT([date],getdate())) FOR [CreateDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [common].[BU] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_BU_CreateTime]  DEFAULT (CONVERT([time],getdate())) FOR [CreateTime]
GO

ALTER TABLE [common].[BU]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_BU_Industry] FOREIGN KEY([IndustryID])
REFERENCES [common].[Industry] ([ID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [common].[BU] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_BU_Industry]
GO
```

When I try to run this script, I get following error

> The specified schema name "common" either does not exist or you do
>   not have permission to use it.

I don't know what is the meaning of common here.Thanks

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Your tables are 'grouped' (for want of better word) in schemas (google for it). You should run

```
CREATE SCHEMA common
```

And likewise for all other schemas.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know it was silly question. But I really didn't know

Answer (score 0):

you can create any not found Schema:
Database-Security-Schema-NewSchema

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).